# Is this BJT reverse \$\beta\$ believable?

Tags: transistors, bjt

Looking at the manufacturer's spice model for the Rohm [2SC4713](https://www.rohm.com/products/transistors/bipolar-transistors/standard-bipolar-transistors/2sc4713k-product) BJT, I was struck by the high reverse \$\beta\$:

> - BR=123.13

Is a value this high believable or an obvious misprint?  Typically BJTs have a reverse \$\beta\$ value somewhere in the range 1 to 10.

Possibly the best way to find out is buy a device and test it!

Comment: Seems hard to believe, but there are transistors with reverse betas in the ~250 range.

Comment: Zetex (now Diodes, Inc) alone has quite a few with high reverse betas. The FMMT497, FZT1047A/48A/49A/51A. FZT1147A, FZT788B/89A/90A, FZT948/68, and more. It may not be a misprint. The FZT1047A shows BF=550 and BR=400 and the FZT788B shows BF=770 and BR=350!!

Comment: @jonk I still think of Zetex as the new name for Ferranti Semiconductors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heterojunction bipolar transistors (**HBT**s) feature high reverse current gains. The HBT are devices that have in their base region the semiconductor with a different bandgap than  in the other regions.  For example, Infineon's BFP840FESD (citing the product datasheet:

> The BFP840FESD is a discrete RF heterojunction bipolar transistor
> (HBT) with an integrated ESD protection suitable for 5 GHz band
> applications

), well, Infineon's BFP840FESD can have a `BR=108` with `BF=946.1`, as one can see in the BFP840FESD model:

```
GBJT 22 11 33 44 ID="Q1" TNOM=25 IS=2.009e-016 BF=946.1 &
    NF=1 VAF=300 IKF=0.1993 ISE=6.26e-015 NE=2 BR=108 &
    NR=1 VAR=1.288 IKR=0.0007328 ISC=8.126e-016 NC=2 &
    RB=17 IRB=0 RBM=1 RE=0.05 RC=4.145 XTB=-2.276 &
    EG=1.11 XTI=0 CJE=1.3e-013 VJE=0.6 MJE=0.5 TF=7.494e-013 &
    XTF=17.49 VTF=0.5295 ITF=1.025 PTF=4.667 CJC=1.1e-014 &
    VJC=0.67 MJC=0.88 XCJC=0.4894 TR=1.793e-009 CJS=3e-013 &
    MJS=0.5 VJS=0.7 FC=0.352 KF=6.4e-012 AF=1.44
```

Of all the HBT flavors with this feature (abrupt junction, graded junction, graded base, double HBT), this feature is most pronounced in the double heterojunction bipolar transistor: `BR` ~ `BF`. The double HBT is a symmetrical device like unipolar transistors, although the HBT is definitely bipolar using both majority and minority carriers for the device operation. See the slides of the Purdue University [course ECE606, Solid State Devices, Heterojunction Bipolar Transistor](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eee606/downloads/ECE606_f12_Lecture20.pdf), pages 20 and 24.

Disclaimer: I have not found any evidence in the documentation indicating that the 2SC4713K is an HBT device.

Comment: Looking at the datasheet and comparing with e.g., the Infineon device, it does look consistent with a HBT - apart from the high \$\beta\$R, the breakdown voltages are fairly low (esp. E-B), and the fT is decent.